# text to xml conversion

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter

I have one problem in which I have to convert text(string) into XML. 
Format in text file is not defined. But one file contains similar format of data. Format changes file to file. So php code should able to identify the formate and convert the file to xml.

It is also not predefined that file is comma/tab/space separated.

Is there any support from codeigniter?

Thank you.

Comment: string in text File is also not xml string.

Comment: @nir if you want to be answered, yes.

Comment: Put some examples of what you have and what you expect, your description is very vague

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want code to transform input we can't see, and whose format you say is not defined, into something useful? You're on the wrong site - you want a forum for conjuring tricks.

Comment: Hi. you got it in a right manner. I know it is very vague  to explain but yes, i think this can be done some way.